# (obj instanceof ObjectClass) not working?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, instanceof, typechecking

Given the class:

```
class Day {
    constructor(year, month, day) {
        this._moment = new Moment()
        this.year = year || this._moment.year()
        this.month = month || this._moment.month()
        this.day = day || this._moment.date()
    }
}
```

I have `let day = new Day()` and pass that through a couple function calls.
But later I check this object with `day instanceof Day` and it returns false.
When I `console.log(day)` in chrome I get `Day {_moment: Moment, year: 2016, month: 9, day: 17}`.

With having the prefix of Day in the console log just before I check with instanceof cannot figure out why `day instanceof Day` is returning false.

Any ideas?

edit:

```
console.log('Day: ', day)
console.log('Day: ', typeof day)
console.log('Day: ', day instanceof Day)
```

Output:

```
Day:  Day {_moment: Moment, year: 2016, month: 9, day: 17}
    _moment: Moment
    day: 17
    month: 9
    year: 2016
    __proto__: Object(anonymous function)
Day:  object
Day:  false
```

Comment: It Works For Me® - please produce a _Small Self-Contained Example_

Comment: Its part of a larger project so I'm not exactly sure what is causing the issue, therefore what to extract.

Comment: Probably you're loading the module twice (in two environments?) or have duplicated it in some other way.

Comment: @Bergi this sounds possible. Can you give me an example of how I could load the module twice?

Comment: No, there are many ways, and I cannot possibly know which one to blame in your case. You haven't even specified whether you are on the client or server side.

Comment: The bug only happens client side. Also I'm not sure what you mean by loading the module twice.

Answer (score 2):

@Bergi was correct, in one import of the Day class I wrote:
    import Day from '../lib/Day'

Webpack then generated another type of Day that was being used in that part of my codebase. Tip: always use lower case string on imports and require.